# Is `list()` considered a function?

Tags: python, list, function

`list` is obviously [a built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) in Python. I saw a comment under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645813/10147399) question which calls `list()` a *built-in function*. And when we check the documentation, it is, indeed, included in [Built-in functions list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) but the documentation again states:

> Rather than being a function, list is actually a mutable sequence type

Which brings me to my question: Is `list()` considered a function? Can we refer to it as a *built-in function*?

If we were talking about C++, I'd say we are just calling the constructor, but I am not sure if the term `constructor` applies to Python (never encountered its use in this context).

Comment: I'd say "constructor" is close enough. After all, if you have any other custom class, say `Foo`, then `Foo` is also a `type`, but also a callable function (the constructor).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173300/why-are-many-python-built-in-standard-library-functions-actually-classes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`list` is a `type`, which means it is defined somewhere as a class, just like `int` and `float`.

```
>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
```

If you check its definition in `builtins.py` (the actual code is implemented in C):

```
class list(object):
    """
    Built-in mutable sequence.

    If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list.
    The argument must be an iterable if specified.
    """

    ...

    def __init__(self, seq=()): # known special case of list.__init__
        """
        Built-in mutable sequence.

        If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list.
        The argument must be an iterable if specified.
        # (copied from class doc)
        """
        pass
```

So, `list()` is not a function. It is just calling `list.__init__()` (with some arguments which are irrelevant for this discussion) just like any call to `CustomClass()` is doing.

Thanks for @jpg for adding in the comments: classes and functions in Python have a common property: they are both considered as *callables*, which means they are allowed to be invoked with `()`. There is a built-in function `callable` that checks if the given argument is callable:

```
>> callable(1)
False
>> callable(int)
True
>> callable(list)
True
>> callable(callable)
True
```

`callable` is also defined in `builtins.py`:

```
def callable(i_e_, some_kind_of_function): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    Return whether the object is callable (i.e., some kind of function).

    Note that classes are callable, as are instances of classes with a
    __call__() method.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Conceptually in Python, it's worth noting classes with `__init__` and functions are both *callable* objects. They just share a common feature. The built-in [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) lets you test this.

Comment: Now my understanding is: No, it is not a function despite being in the built in functions list, but it's rather a `type` object which just happens to be *callable*, and yes `__init__` is in fact referred as *constructor* in Python. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ayxan Not *per se*. I personally don't like to refer to `__init__` as a constructor (because then how would you refer to `__new__`?). As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) suggests, `__init__` is called only after the object is created, and *initializes* its attributes, it does not create it.

Comment: The signature for `callable()` is `callable(obj)` - it expects an object of any type.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `list()`, you're invoking the constructor of the `list` class (`list.__init__`).

If you have any doubt about the use of the term "constructor" in Python, this is the exact word that the implementers of `list` chose to refer to `__init__`:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2695